# what is an instance type in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm learning web scraping and trying to understand the code from some post step by step.

```
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.aflcio.org/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts')
```

I want see what's the type of r. So I do

```
type(r)
```

This gives me

```
instance
```

I never seen this before. I saw some people have the same question in stackoverfolw. Most answers are saying old-style classes. But I don't quite understand what it means? Can anyone explain it in more plain language?

Comment: You probably want to start reading [here](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) and follow the links.